# No data in tables when copying sqlite database to ios app

Tags: ios, sql, database, sqlite

I'm using core data and am pre-populating it using a SQlite database that I provide in the bundle. It's been working fine for a while, however I've just edited the database and when I copy it over there is no data displayed. So I opened the database that is on the ios simulator, in base, and I found an sqlitemaster table that contains lots of SQL statements such as CREATE TABLE..., but the tables I want don't contain any data.

What's weirder is that after a while the database is fine and all the data is in it as normal. Is this because the statements in the sqlitemaster table were executed?

Has this happened to anybody else? I don't know whether it's because I've upgraded to iOS 7 or not? If anybody could point me in the right direction that would be great

Comment: When you update the pre-packaged version of your DB you generally want to delete the app in the simulator/device.  Otherwise your "first time through" logic won't copy the new DB into the working directory.

Comment: Yeh I've done that, I think I'm finding a solution though!

Comment: You do know how to use `sqlite3` from the command line, right?  (*sqlitemaster* contains the definitions of the other tables.  It doesn't actually contain any data from the other tables.)

Answer (score 0):

The latest iOS Core Data SQLite backend uses journaling. You should notice .shm and .wal files in the same directory as what you assumed was your main sqlite backing store for Core Data. This data *eventually* gets into the main file, but journaling optimizes some situations for Core Data configured with SQLite.

As a developer, you generally never care about this from within the app, but if you are trying to inspect the persisted Core Data graph via the actual file, you'll need to be aware.

Comment: I've managed to fix it by using the journal_mode: DELETE method. Do you know if there's a way to do it still using Wal journaling though?

Comment: You're going to have to turn off journaling while you import. Then turn it back on with `PRAGMA wal_checkpoint`.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a look around and the journaling was causing it to go all weird. Found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758834/prepopulated-core-data-sql-store-with-new-write-ahead-log-wal-journaling) which shows the same problem I had. If anyone else has this look at that post